# Cómo obtener una suma entre columnas con datos faltantes (RStudio)

Tags: r, rstudio, timeseries, sumatoria

Tengo un pronóstico de serie de tiempo en primeras diferencias que quiero transformar en valores absolutos. Para eso tengo en una columna el resultado del pronóstico en primeras diferencias y en otra los logaritmos que fueron diferenciados. Si sumo el resultados en diferencias con los valores en logaritmo obtengo el pronóstico en valores absolutos (obviamente tras hacer el antilogaritmo). La solución teórica es sencilla, uso una suma entre columnas y listo. La cuestión está en que, como los valores en logaritmo a partir de la fecha de pronóstico son cero (no hay datos observados), porque el pronóstico está en diferencias, al sumar eso con el resultado en diferencias no me arroja lo que después puedo transformar en valores absolutos, si no más bien cero más el resultado en diferencias.

Esto utilicé para la suma acumulada

```
> X1=data.table(X) 
> X1[ , forecast2 := dLog+shift(Log1)]
```

Pero como mencioné, a partir de la fecha de pronóstico se vuelve inútil. Quisiera utilizar un loop en el que el resultado de la suma sea el que fuese utilizado nuevamente para el calcular el valor siguiente, algo como arrastrar las formulas en Excel, pero apenas estoy iniciando y casi no comprendo las funciones de bucle.
Alguna ayuda por favor. Disculpen si no me di a entender, estaré atento a las consultas sobre el caso.

```
         Fecha      dLog     Log1    forecast2
1   2010-01-01  0.0000000000  11.33369           NA
2   2010-02-01 -0.1523160417  11.18138 11.181375096
...
   
20 2022-10-01 -0.0875620805  11.96225 11.962254337
20 2022-11-01  0.2729498353  12.23520 12.235204172
20 2022-12-01 -0.0966344371  12.13857 12.138569735
20 2023-01-01  0.0044841640   0.00000 12.143053899
20 2023-02-01  0.0044923632   0.00000  0.004492363
20 2023-03-01 -0.0035687537   0.00000 -0.003568754
20 2023-04-01  0.0318408607   0.00000  0.031840861
20 2023-05-01 -0.0059899946   0.00000 -0.005989995
20 2023-06-01  0.0043332038   0.00000  0.004333204
21 2023-07-01  0.0065373703   0.00000  0.006537370
21 2023-08-01  0.0032823826   0.00000  0.003282383
21 2023-09-01  0.0045078426   0.00000  0.004507843
21 2023-10-01  0.0045966920   0.00000  0.004596692
21 2023-11-01  0.0043048361   0.00000  0.004304836
21 2023-12-01  0.0044305164   0.00000  0.0044305
```

Comment: Se puede usar la función de `cumsum` para obtener una suma acumulada

Comment: Cuando la columna Log1 empieza a ser 0 -porque inicia el pronóstico a futuro- la función cumsum no utiliza los resultados de las sumas anteriores, por lo que solo suma la columna dLog